# How to get child text text via script on button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button with a text child object.
I have a script on this button. How to get the text of the button's child object through this script?

[image]

Here is the script hanging on the button.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class monumentButtonAppy : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public void ButtonPressed()
    {
        // DataHolders.Monument
        SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
    }
}
```

The received text from the button, I need to apply it to the variable "DataHolders.Monument"

Comment: [`GetComponentInChilren<Text>()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInChildren.html) ? or even better already have a field for it in the Inspector `public Text text;` .. or accordingly `TMP_Text` instead of `Text` if using TextMeshPro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could drag and drop your text to this [SerializableField] as text object in Unity Editor.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class monumentButtonAppy : MonoBehaviour
{   
[SerialiableField] Text text;
public void ButtonPressed()
{
    // DataHolders.Monument
    SceneManager.LoadScene(3);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way if you have script on button GameObject

```
button.gameObject.transform.GetChild(textIndex /*Usually it's 0*/).GetComponent<Text>().text="Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

button.GetComponentInChildren();
Or make a public Text text,and drag your text to it in unity Editor.